# Hide URL when sending with email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, url, smtp

I am developing iOS app that sending selected pdfs(urls) stored in firebase with using SMTP. I don't want to be seen urls in mail.

It should be like this "https://...." = "Document1 or proper name"

Is it possible ?

[image]

```
func sendEmail() {
     
    
     let message = SKPSMTPMessage()
     message.relayHost = "smtp.gmail.com"
     message.login = "****@gmail.com"
     message.pass = "*****"
     message.requiresAuth = true
     message.wantsSecure = true
     message.relayPorts = [587]
     message.fromEmail = "****@gmail.com"
     message.toEmail = "****@gmail.com"
     message.subject = "subject"
     let messagePart = [kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey: "Hi,\n\n Please see the requested documents below\n\n\(getmailpdf.joined(separator: "\n\n\n"))"]
     message.parts = [messagePart]
     message.delegate = self
     message.send()
 }
```

Comment: Send your email as HTML

Comment: @jnpdx i am using SKPSMTPMessage library. How can I do that ?

Comment: You haven't shown any of your code, but I assume you're sending your message as `text/plain` right now. You'll probably set that to `text/html` and then use HTML for your message. That's all a guess, though. I've never used that library.

Comment: @jnpdx I have added it. Selected pdfs in getmailpdf:[String].

Comment: See where it says "text/plain" -- my guess is you'll have to change that to "text/html". Then, you can make links in your HTML -- plenty of resources available about how to do that.